# asyncio REST API dynamic routing

Tags: python-3.x, rest, routes, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to create a REST API application for a python 3 asyncio program using the [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library.

In this program I am managing objects, comprised of more objects,
for example managing customer shopping cart, containing many different products.

When adding a new object (product) to a container (shopping cart),
I'd like for it to be a sub-application with unique functionalities, for example, dairy products will have expiration date and beverages will have alcohol percentage.

The problem is that the different paths of different products needs to be resolved to different sub-applications, for example:
if our paths format is:
`/{cart_id}/{product_name}`  then:

> `/1/milk`  --> Needs to be resolved to the Dairy sub-application, while
>
> `/1/whiskey`  --> Needs to be resolved to the beverages sub-application.

I also want the sub-application to have access to the {cart_id} value.

In total, there would be only about 3 of these sub-application types so no need for a very complicated solution.

I'm currently planing on overriding the aiohttp.Router class to disable it from freezing to allow the dynamic addition of routes,
but that is pretty terrible.

If anyone has faced similar problem or could point me to a better solution it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that overriding the Router to disable freezing is a bad idea.

Better to do your own custom routing. Eg. a view which receives all requests and then decides which other view should deal with each request.

Take a look at [Custom Routing Criteria](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web.html#custom-routing-criteria) in the docs.

Comment: This solution is suited for only a single path, I'd like to have something to allow completley different sets of paths for different types of products.

Comment: You can still do that with different paths, just use [variables](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web.html#variable-resources) in the path for the router view.